# Python 3 dict sort by value inside list of dicts?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

Is there a simple way to sort the following Python d:dict by value of key '#1'. The output should be as shown in o:dict ?
I want to be able to print in different kind of orders like a html tabel with asc/desc key.
I know how to sort a simple key:value with the sorted() but cant figure out how to do it, when the value is as shown below !!
I'm using CPython 3.9

```
d:dict = {  'aaa': {'#1': 9,  '#2':34,  '#3': 5},
            'bbb': {'#1': 11, '#2': 15, '#3': 7},
            'ccc': {'#1': 6,  '#2': 3,  '#3': 6} }

o:dict = {  'ccc': {'#1': 6,  '#2': 3,  '#3': 6},
            'aaa': {'#1': 9,  '#2': 34,  '#3': 5},
            'bbb': {'#1': 11, '#2': 15, '#3': 7}   }
```

Comment: It's a dict. Why do you care about the order? (which will not be consistent across versions of Python)

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @DeepSpace CPython dictionaries are ordered by insertion starting with Python 3.6, which is the oldest supported Python version.

Comment: @Boris You meant Python 3.7, which still does not mean OP should bother **ordering an existing** dictionary.

Comment: Also note that this may depend on the version of Python you're using .. dictionaries are only guaranteed to have insertion ordering (or perhaps any particular ordering) from 3.7 onwards (though from 3.6 the most common implementation did this) .. as **DeepSpace** notes, ordering them is not normally necessary. For a particular order prior to 3.7, a [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) should be used

Comment: @DeepSpace no, I meant **C**Python 3.6. It was implemented in CPython 3.6 and then became required for all other Python implementations starting with Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
d = {  'aaa': {'#1': 9,  '#2':34,  '#3': 5},
       'bbb': {'#1': 11, '#2': 15, '#3': 7},
       'ccc': {'#1': 6,  '#2': 3,  '#3': 6} }

o = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]["#1"]))
```

Comment: Thanks Boris .. I was pretty close with that solution, but missed the [1] myself .. Thanks a lot